# why the ARP packets I received always have the same MAC address?

Tags: python, scapy, arp

I want to find all survival hosts in a LAN, so I use the function in Scapy:

```py
frame = Ether(dst="FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF")/ARP(pdst=ipscan)
ans, unans = srp(frame, timeout=2, verbose=False)
```

Then the `ans.show()` shows that the packets I receive always have the same MAC address，regardless of what dst ip I use.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRxi3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you edit your question to include the output of `arp -a`?

Comment: thank you for your advice!  I seemingly got the answer,maybe the mac address is of the gateway of my school，I got it via wireshark. but I just wonder why didn't it return the mac address of my laptop，because I used wifi？

Comment: You should probably ask another question because this is one different :)